# Cannot use alias from SELECT clause in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering, where-clause, column-alias

USE stormtrooper_java;

```
SELECT imperial_battlegroup.BGID, imperial_battlegroup.Designation, imperial_battlegroup.HQ_LocationX, imperial_battlegroup.HQ_LocationY,
stormtrooper_unit.STUID, stormtrooper_unit.UnitCmd, stormtrooper_unit.UnitType, stormtrooper_unit.Location_X, stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y,
ABS(stormtrooper_unit.Location_X - stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y) AS XYRange 
from imperial_battlegroup inner join
     stormtrooper_unit
     on imperial_battlegroup.BGID = stormtrooper_unit.UnitCmd
WHERE Designation = 'Battle Group I' and UnitType = 'Aslt Infantry' AND 
      XYRange > 100;
```

When I execute the file without `XYRange > 100` it works very well, but I do need that filtering logic in the query.

How can I adjust my query to filter the results by this calculated condition?

Comment: Rahul got it below - should have caught that one!

Comment: show your schema, please! there is nothing like separate logic for using 3rd condition

Comment: Are you getting an error (if so, what is it) or are you getting no data?

Comment: You cannot use aliases from the SELECT clause in the WHERE (or FROM) clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT imperial_battlegroup.BGID, imperial_battlegroup.Designation, 
imperial_battlegroup.HQ_LocationX, imperial_battlegroup.HQ_LocationY,
stormtrooper_unit.STUID, stormtrooper_unit.UnitCmd, 
stormtrooper_unit.UnitType, stormtrooper_unit.Location_X, 
stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y,
ABS(stormtrooper_unit.Location_X - stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y) AS XYRange 
from imperial_battlegroup inner join
stormtrooper_unit
on imperial_battlegroup.BGID = stormtrooper_unit.UnitCmd 
WHERE Designation = 'Battle Group I' and UnitType = 'Aslt Infantry' AND 
ABS(stormtrooper_unit.Location_X - stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y) > 100;
```

Just updated the last line, rest everything is same.

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they miss an excellent opportunity to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not allow you to use column aliases in `WHERE` clauses.  It does extend the `HAVING`, so one solution is:

```
SELECT bg.BGID, bg.Designation, imperial_battlegroup.HQ_LocationX, bg.HQ_LocationY,
        u.STUID, u.UnitCmd, u.UnitType, u.Location_X, u.Location_Y,
ABS(stormtrooper_unit.Location_X - stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y) AS XYRange 
from imperial_battlegroup bg inner join
     stormtrooper_unit
     on bg.BGID = u.UnitCmd
WHERE Designation = 'Battle Group I' and UnitType = 'Aslt Infantry' 
HAVING XYRange > 100;
```

Another option is to repeat the expression in the `WHERE`.

Comment: It's the best solution but I just wanted to done it without 'having'

Answer (score 0):

Its forbidden to use alias in where clause. So use the function itself

```
where ABS(stormtrooper_unit.Location_X - stormtrooper_unit.Location_Y)> 100
```

Comment: Not at all @MohammadAlamri